# while data == 1 run action one time

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, loops

From an api, I receive a data. It returns two values: 1 and -1.
I receive one data per second and in series of 1 or -1.

What I want is that when data goes to 1 you execute the action only once, and when it goes to -1 do the same action always once.

My problem is that for the moment I can't make the action happen only once. The action is repeated as long as data == 1 or data == -1

Moreover I need the code to continue to execute even if I'm not out of the loop.

Thanks for your help

```
signal_result = APIDATA

while signal_result == 1:
      self.action(signal_result)
                
while signal_result == -1:
      self.action(signal_result)
```

Comment: We need a little more information. Your code shows a call to: `self.action()`. Does this mean all the posted code is due to run inside another method? Do you expect this method to run in an infinite loop, or should it be called every so often?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep track of the *previous* value, and if it is different, perform the action:

```
# at the very start, initialise 
previous_result = 0  # Some value that is different from 1 or -1

# ...
# ...

# When a signal is received:
    global previous_result
    signal_result = APIDATA
    if signal_result != previous_result:
        previous_result = signal_result
        self.action(signal_result)
```